# Can a C++ container contain template objects? Getting error

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the following error:
"unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Kty', expected a real type"

The code I am trying to compile is something like this:

```
template <typename T> class TypeX;

template <typename T>
class TypeY
{

...
    private:
    std::set<TypeX> m_tree;
}
```

Btw, including "TypeX.h" (which is a template class) instead of the forward declaration doesn't change anything.

What I am gathering from this error is that since TypeX is "unspecialized" - in the sense that "T" is not defined and TypeX is still in template form, it cannot be the basis of a std::set. But I really want TypeX to be a template of T also such that from within TypeY, I can initialize a new TypeX (template of T) and then insert that new object to m_tree.

Can this be done? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TypeX` requires a template parameter. You are not giving it one when you creating the `std::set`

You can change your code to something more like this

```
std::set< TypeX<T> > m_tree;
```

Comment: I'm not up on the latest version of the C++ standard, but don't earlier versions require this to be written with a space between the two `>`s?

Comment: @jwodder Fixed just in case.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Caesar. That fixed that problem. Two follow up questions below. (since I can't insert new lines here)